# Toshiba Satellite C655-S5132 laptop fails to boot on first few attempts

Tags: boot, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite C655-S5132 laptop (Windows 7).

If I leave it alone for a while and then try to boot it, it fails.  The fan turns on and then gradually winds down to a stop. The display doesn't turn on at all. The power LED comes on and stays on.  After trying to boot it several times it will eventually boot normally.

If I shut it down and turn it back on without waiting, it boots back up just fine. It's only after leaving it off for 10-20+ minutes that I start to have a problem again.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: does it happen when plugged in or not?? have you noticed any other odd behavior in that room like more burnt out lightbulbs, blown fuses in that room or area where the computer is kept? Try moving the laptop and try starting it up in a different area. Then I would work closer to the laptop. Cords etc...

Comment: I've tried booting with just the battery, just the plug, and both.  Each time it exhibits the same behavior.  I've also tried booting it, not only in different rooms, but in different neighborhoods (incidentally), so I don't think it could possibly have anything to do with the power coming from the wall.

Comment: plugged in without the battery in your laptop?

Comment: Yep.  I've tried booting with just the battery, just the plug, and both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fact that the fans start and then stop, I would hazard the guess that the problem
is with the power supply unit (PSU) which need replacement.
My guess is that some internal capacitor inside the PSU is dying, so is slow to recharge,
so that several tries are necessary before it recharges enough in order to boot.

While replacing the PSU, I would also replace the battery, just for good measures.

In any case, if you are not a technician, then better let a technician have a look at it
in case some connection is loose inside.
Preferably a technician that knows your laptop model.

You could also try to completely discharge all internal capacitors
using the [computer power button trick](https://superuser.com/questions/283109/why-does-pulling-the-power-cord-then-pressing-the-power-button-fix-a-non-booting)
(although I don't really believe this will help) :
Disconnect everything from the laptop including battery and power,
push the power button a few times to completely discharge,
leave for 30 minutes and then reconnect.