# Asus laptop X50R not starting when pressing power button

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, bios, power-supply

I have an Asus Notebook (x50R model). Is a really old laptop with like 10 years

I have a problem I can't understand:

- If I press the power button it doesn't start
- If I unplug the power and remove and put the BIOS battery (or press the power button for a minute) it starts correctly again, even can turn on and off multiple times, until I unplug the power, after that the power button does not work again until I reset the BIOS config again.

I tried flashing the last version of the BIOS firmware (502) but didn't work.

Also tried playing with the BIOS config: enabling and disabling the fast boot or the silent boot with no results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try too keep the BIOS(CMOS)-Battery out the battery unplugged and then do you power on trick with the power cord plugged in and then shut down the laptop. Can you then after connecting only the power cord use the power button? Thinking i might be the battery pack?

Comment: So, reading the manual for this laptop suggests that there is a feature referred to as "Thermal Power Control."  If you are running the computer in maximum performance mode, it seems possible that the computer overheats, and that over the course of your ministrations, it cools down. (Page 50 of the English manual, version E2915 at this URL: http://support.asus.com.cn/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=X50R&os=17 ).

Answer (score 4):

It might be that static charge remains on the motherboard and prevents it
from booting up, so the motherboard refuses to boot up to prevent damage.

You can dissipate the accumulated charge by removing battery and
power adapter and pressing and holding the power button for half a minute.
After that, plug the power cord back and try to reboot the computer normally.

If the above procedure helps, even once, then accumulated charge is indeed
the problem.

You may solve the problem by buying an anti-static mat,
or by grounding the static electricity by touching the internal metal frame
of the computer's case while it is plugged into the electrical socket.
It is also possible that this is a problem with your power cord not being
properly grounded - use a three pronged plug and a grounded outlet
(and if that helps then you have a short-circuit or a non-isolated
power cable touching the motherboard).

A better solution may require help by a professional.

For more information see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/283109/why-does-pulling-the-power-cord-then-pressing-the-power-button-fix-a-non-booting).

Comment: Hidden IT secret right hear, took me 5yr+ to learn of it & I don't completely understand the reasoning. Maybe the battery is also faulty, try to follow @harrymc advice & try it without the battery connected to isolate if battery at fault

Comment: @gregg: This bleeds off the charge left in the motherboard capacitors.

Comment: I know that, I meant YOUR advice seems to be a hidden secret & I am glad you're telling it! Based on the users wording it seems he can get the PC on, but the second he removes power cord he tends to have trouble so I'm guessing its a glitch with laptop battery (or motherboard as you've stated)

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you remove the BIOS battery (this is generally called the CMOS battery), and I assume you put it back in. Have you tried replacing the battery? It is usually a CR2032 lithium battery, which you can pick up quite cheaply online - make sure to check the battery on your particular device and ensure it is the same.

When the CMOS battery is flat, it generally just means that the stored settings in the nonvolatile BIOS memory are erased every time the device loses power, but I have seen a few examples of it causing a device to fail to power on.

I would also recommend checking the power adaptor, power supply unit and battery for damage or defects and consider obtaining replacements if necessary. If there are no obvious defects, check each components individually (e.g. try to use the laptop with only the battery, use the power adaptor to charge another laptop if possible, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I put back the battery, yes. Also changed the battery for another CR2032 with no result. =(

Answer (score 0):

Try press and *hold* the power button about 5 seconds to power it off. Then press it again, this time in a normal way - *don't holding it*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't anything. =( I need to press for a minute for getttng results